# file CheckOut() Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, checkout

I am trying to check out file but I am getting weird exception, which I don't understand.

**ServerExeption was unhanded 
serverRelativeUrl
Parameter name: Specified value is not supported for the serverRelativeUrl parameter.**

Could you please explain me what does it mean, what what I am doing wrong?

```
public void CheckOut(string filePath)
{

   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext context = new     
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("http://sharepointsite");
        context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web web = context.Web;
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath);

   file.CheckOut();
   context.Load(web);
   context.Load(file);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Is your filePath starting with a slash symbol (/)? I've noticed the same error while using the REST API, and I've missed / at the beginning of the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass as parameter the server-relative URL for the file:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(filePath);
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = 
    web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(uri.LocalPath);
context.Load(file)
context.ExecuteQuery();

if (file.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
{
   file.CheckOut();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunatelly, still the same issue. :(

Comment: It works well, if I am using Web services instead of Model object. But I really want to use DLL because whole my functionality rely on it.

Comment: Did you the Load(file) and ExecuteQuery() before the CheckOut ?

Comment: Yes, I was trying both ways. But getting the same exception. Exception happens on context.ExecuteQuery(); line

Comment: Check you parameter format. Ex: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = 
    web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Site/DocLibrary/wiki.xml"); The URL should be under your SharePoint server: http://sharepointsite